# DCOM and OpenMPI

Tags: dcom, openmpi

I did the DCOMCNFG with both the launch and the remote access permissions, granting my local logon on each node . Have OpenMPI_v1.6.1-x64 installed in root and remote machines. HAve specified the path of .exe in the target node. But while running the .exe from root node with mpirun. I am getting the following error:

```
D:\x64\Release>mpirun -np 2 -hostfile myhostfile.txt MPISample.exe
connecting to n1234
username:toney.mathew
password:********
Save Credential?(Y/N) n
[n1205:04420] Could not connect to namespace cimv2 on node n1234. Error code =-2147023174
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpirun was unable to start the specified application as it encountered an error.

More information may be available above.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
[n1205:04420] [[28225,0],0] ORTE_ERROR_LOG: A message is attempting to be sent t
o a process whose contact information is unknown in file ..\..\..\openmpi-1.6.1\
orte\mca\rml\oob\rml_oob_send.c at line 145
[n1205:04420] [[28225,0],0] attempted to send to [[28225,0],1]: tag 1
[n1205:04420] [[28225,0],0] ORTE_ERROR_LOG: A message is attempting to be sent t
o a process whose contact information is unknown in file ..\..\..\openmpi-1.6.1\
orte\orted\orted_comm.c at line 126
```

and to be more specific, i am using windows7-64bit os in both nodes,with same same user loged in.

Comment: Not suitable for SO, more likely for [superuser](http://superuser.com/) or [serverfault](http://serverfault.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turned off firewall, and it worked smoothly.